# Mobile test for Browserstacks boots a device but throws AndroidDevice error

Tags: c#, mobile, specflow, playwright, browserstack

I am currently using the following:

- PlayWright.Microsoft
- Specflow
- Nunit Framework

I am trying to combine a mobile browserstack test with the above frameworks. the way I set it up is having the logic of connecting to browserstack in my stepdefinitions for specflow

here is the logic  in a feature file:

```
Scenario: Mobile test for browserstack  
Given I setup my browserstack connection  
When I navigate to Rail Informatieportaal Test
```

and the class behind this:

```
using Microsoft.Playwright;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;
using RPAutomation.Drivers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;  

using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace RPAutomation.StepDefinitions
{
[Binding}
public class PlaywrightTestSteps
{
private IPlaywright playwright;
private IBrowser browser;
private IPage page;
private readonly string bsUsername =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME") ?? "MYCREDENTIALS";
private readonly string bsAccessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY") ?? "MYCREDENTIALS";
private readonly string bsBuildName = "playwright-build-1";

        [Given(@"I setup my browserstack connection")]
        public async Task GivenISetupMyBrowserstackConnection()
        {
            playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
    
            var browserstackOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["osVersion"] = "12.0",
                ["deviceName"] = "Samsung Galaxy S22", // "Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra", "Google Pixel 7 Pro", "OnePlus 9", etc.
                ["browserName"] = "chrome",
                ["realMobile"] = "true",
                ["name"] = "My android playwright test",
                ["build"] = bsBuildName,
                ["browserstack.playwrightLogs"] = "true",
                ["browserstack.console"] = "verbose",
                ["browserstack.username"] = bsUsername,
                ["browserstack.accessKey"] = bsAccessKey
            };
    
            var capsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(browserstackOptions);
            var cdpUrl = $"wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps={Uri.EscapeDataString(capsJson)}";
            browser = await playwright.Chromium.ConnectAsync(cdpUrl);
            page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    
        }
    
        [When(@"I navigate to Rail Informatieportaal Test")]
        public async Task WhenINavigateToRailInformatieportaalTest()
        {
            await page.GotoAsync("https://www.railinformatieportaal-test.nl/");
        }
    
        [When(@"I click the login portrait on mobile")]
        public async Task WhenIClickTheLoginPortraitOnMobile()
        {
            await page.Locator("//a[@href='authentication/login']").ClickAsync();
        }
```

The above code starts the device but will NOT open a browser
the result is visible in the BrowserStack Dashboard:

[image: test result]

however the test throws an error in Visual Studio Test Explorer:

> Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'AndroidDevice' was not present in the dictionary.

**I need to know how to actually start a browser on the phone test and how to fix the error that is throwing**

the test succeeds on a normal machine with the following code:

```
Scenario: Regular machine browserstack
Given I Setup My Browserstack Connection
When I navigate to Rail Informatieportaal Test
```

and the code behind this:

```
using Microsoft.Playwright;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace RPAutomation.StepDefinitions
{
    [Binding]
    public class PlaywrightTestSteps
    {
        private IPlaywright playwright;
        private IBrowser browser;
        private IPage page;

        [Given(@"I Setup My Browserstack Connection")]
        public async Task GivenISetupMyBrowserStackConnection()
        {
            playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            Dictionary<string, string> browserstackOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"name", "Playwright first sample test"},
                {"build", "playwright-dotnet-1"},
                {"os", "osx"},
                {"os_version", "catalina"},
                {"browser", "chrome"}, // allowed browsers are `chrome`, `edge`, `playwright-chromium`, `playwright-firefox` and `playwright-webkit`
                {"browserstack.username", "MYCREDENTIALS"},
                {"browserstack.accessKey", "MYCREDENTIALS"}
            };
            string capsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(browserstackOptions);
            string cdpUrl = "wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(capsJson);
            browser = await playwright.Chromium.ConnectAsync(cdpUrl);
            page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        }

        [When(@"I navigate to Rail Informatieportaal Test")]
        public async Task WhenINavigateToRailInformatieportaalTest()
        {
            await page.GotoAsync("https://www.railinformatieportaal-test.nl/");
        
        }


        [AfterScenario]
        public async Task AfterScenario()
        {
            if (playwright != null)
            {
                await browser.CloseAsync();
                playwright.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'AndroidDevice' was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Helpers.EnumHelper.FromValueString[TEnum](String value) in /_/src/Playwright/Helpers/EnumHelper.cs:line 83
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Converters.JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.Read[TEnum](Utf8JsonReader& reader) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Converters/JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Converters.JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.EnumMemberConverter`1.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Converters/JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.cs:line 94
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadUsingMetadata[TValue](JsonElement element, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Playwright.Helpers.JsonExtensions.ToObject[T](JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options) in /_/src/Playwright/Helpers/JsonEx
```

I tried refactoring the above to work on a mobile device but thats where the error is throwing

I expected the same test to work on a mobile device

What actually happens is that a test is created, a device is started but a browser is not actually started and the test throws the error

To summarize:

- regular test works with browserstack
- mobile test doesn't work and throws an error

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the stack trace? Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: edited and added the stack trace

Comment: So, which line of your code is throwing the exception? Man, that stack trace isn't giving you much, is it?

Comment: there isnt a line if i have the complete stack it seems its throwing somewhere in the playwright package
:at Microsoft.Playwright.Transport.Converters.JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.Read[TEnum](Utf8JsonReader& reader) in /_/src/Playwright/Transport/Converters/JsonStringEnumMemberConverter.cs:line 56

but that doesn't really help as well

Comment: It does help, because the Playwright framework is throwing the exception. Knowing that can help direct us to an answer. This might be a configuration or dependency issue. Something within the framework barfs at runtime.

Comment: Is there a config file that Playwright is expecting to read?

Comment: not that I am aware of. This is high above my current knowledge level with regards to how these things work together.

i tried something very basic by simply adding 
            var browserstackOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["osVersion"] = "12.0",
                ["AndroidDevice"] = "Samsung Galaxy S22", 
to the options but that generates the same stack trace